# In Wordpress how to add a body class to all interior pages except the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a class to the body tag to all pages **EXCEPT** the homepage. Right now I have.

```
<?php body_class('interior'); ?>
```

But it adds 'interior' to ALL pages including the home page.

What is the best standard way of adding a class to the body tag to all interior pages except the 'home page'?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Comment: `is_front_page()` may also be useful if you are using a static front page as your home page.

Comment: Suddently, I had a [*déjà-vu*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu): "gee, I've [already answered this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/85793/12615)...". :::: Please, read the following Q&A regarding **Multi-posting**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

```
<?php if (!is_home()) body_class('interior'); ?>
```

Unless you mean http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

```
<?php if (!is_front_page()) body_class('interior'); ?>
```

Comment: Can this be another way of writing it? ` <?php body_class( ! is_home() ? "interior" : "" ); ?>`

Comment: @BeEasy if it works and you prefer it there's no harm in using that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is write:

```
<body <?php if (!is_front_page()) body_class('interior'); ?> <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

In this way you add only `class="interior"` in all page except the front page, and you can save the class in the front page, otherwise in you use only the fist php code in the tag `<body>` in home you will not have class.